# Lota character in Facebook make a rubbish

Tags: facebook, unicode, fonts, ascii, non-ascii-characters

when i print this characters in facebook status it makes a rubbish like ‎!̸̶͚͖͖̩̻̩̗͍̮̙̈͊͛̈͒̍̐ͣͩ̋ͨ̓̊̌̈̊́̚͝͠ͅ 
and it seems to be everywhere not in facebook only i searched and it was found to be "Iota" the ninth character in the Greek alphabet , does it appear rubbish because i'm pasting it with non-ascii or another format or what ? 
i'm really interested to know

Comment: Aaaaand now you broke StackOverflow too :) Should a bug report be filed?

Comment: btw, it's `iota`, not `lota` (`i` not `L`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font used doesn't contain that character - not every font contains every Unicode character.

Comment: so it appears as rubbish isn't it supposed to appear as a square []

Comment: I see squares in the text you posted.

Comment: okay , so obviously it's an encoding problem , if u changed the encoding in the browser u'll find it changing to another characters

Comment: Perhaps. See this for other possibilities: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html